# Vim non-greedy search

Tags: vim

I am trying to remove everything up to the first comma of each line in a csv file.
The lines are like:

```
-29.45829963684082~149.14680480957031,-000029.45829963684082, 000149.14680480957031,WGS84
-29.46190071105957~149.09509277343750,-000029.46190071105957, 000149.09509277343750,WGS84
```

When I execute `%s/.*,\\{-}//` it removes everything!

If I use `%s/.*,//` it removes all except WGS84 which is what I would expect.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I thought `\{-}` imposed non-greedy matching in Vim.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3):

I would just use `[^,]*` instead of `.*`. That will make your regex non-greedy for commas.

In terms of why your variant isn't working, you seem to have the objects in your regex the wrong way around. `{-}` is supposed to be equivalent to `*` but non-greedy, and you're *already* used `*` to suck up as much as possible. You also have too many backslashes in there. Try:

```
:%s/.\{-},//
```

instead.

When I do that on your test input, I get:

```
-000029.45829963684082, 000149.14680480957031,WGS84
-000029.46190071105957, 000149.09509277343750,WGS84
```

as expected.

Answer (score 3):

`\{-}` is the  non-greedy matching in Vim, so you should use `\{-}` instead of `*`.

Try:

```
%s/.\{-},//
```

Answer (score 2):

Another route to take is to use the global command.

```
:g//normal dt,
```

Comment: @Conner Oh wow. I never realized that :) I'm so using that from now on!

Comment: @sehe check [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/vimgolf/comments/wmtep/abusing_macros_part_1_normal/) out. :-)

Comment: @Conner Gah. I would have used `:g/^/t.` instead of `:%norm Yp` there. And, of course, `8@:` to exponentially grow the file from there :)

Comment: @sehe yeah it's not all practical... just interesting. That article is written in the context of [vimgolf](http://vimgolf.com/).

Answer (score 1):

here's what you need to do

```
%s/[^,]*//
```